# Angular material checkbox automatically un-checks itself

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a list that I display as checkboxes using `angular-material` (Angular 7). Below I will add code snippet for `.html` and `.ts` files.

Whenever I click on a checkbox it is checked but then immediately un-checked. I entered in debug mode and see that when I click on a checkbox, my `isSelected()` method gets called 4 times by Angular. When I click on it, it immediately goes to checked state. Then it is still checked the second time that Angular calls it. On the third time, it becomes un-checked (meanwhile `isSelected()` is still true). I cannot figure out what I did wrong. What I tried is:

- Switch from `isSelected()` method to a class property (added the `isSelected` boolean field on `myListItem` objects)
- Added bidirectional binding on top of the previous idea
- Switch from `checked` to `ngModel`

Nothing helped. What else to try, I don't know. Please help me out.

`html` snippet:

```js
class MyListItem {
  id: number
  name: string
}

// omitted annotations
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  myList: MyListItem[] = [] // omitted initialization

  isSelected(myListItem: MyListItem): boolean {
    return this.myList.includes(myListItem)
  }

  toggle(myListItem: MyListItem): void {
    // omitted the code, I debugged it and it works correctly: 
    // it adds/removes the item to/from the list
  }
}
```

```html
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let myListItem of myList">
    <mat-checkbox flex="100" (click)="toggle(myListItem)" 
                  [checked]="isSelected(myListItem)">
      {{ myListItem.name }}
    </mat-checkbox>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Comment: post the code on stackbitz this way no one will be able to help

Comment: try to use `(change)` instead of `(click)`

Comment: @quirimmo This also works, thank you, and is, IMO, a neater solution!

Comment: @ArsenSimonean you are welcome :) just posted as answer too for future readers too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `change` event not `click`:

```
<mat-checkbox flex="100" (change)="toggle(myListItem)" 
                  [checked]="isSelected(myListItem)">
      {{ myListItem.name }}
    </mat-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will work but you can add an Event parameter to the toggle function.

```
toggle(myListItem: MyListItem, event: any) { event.preventDefault() }
```

Then in your html:

```
(click)="toggle(myListItem, $event)"
```

Again, Not sure if this will work, but I have found that sometimes these click events will happen automatically, unless the prevent default() function is called

Comment: This worked, thank you, but I will use what @quirimmo suggested- to use (change) instead of (click) because it is neater like that.

Comment: I understand. Just glad a solution was found